# retrieving the public key from keystore

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have created a keystore and it includes private key and public key. I need to retrieve my public key and private key using java codes.  I found a method to retrieve the private key from [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html)
But I cannot find a way to retrieve the public key. Can anyone tell me a way to take my public key out

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm

Comment: I do not need the key pair, i need only the public key

Answer (score 0):

The zeroth entry of the corresponding certificate chain contains the corresponding public key.